# PyCallGraph's GlobbingFilter does not work?

Tags: python, graphviz, pycallgraph

I am using pycallgraph (from within a jupyter notebook) to understand the codebase I'm working on. For some reason, the GlobbingFilter does not seem to work - I can't exclude things using the `GlobbingFilter`

```
from pycallgraph import PyCallGraph, Config, GlobbingFilter
from pycallgraph.output import GraphvizOutput
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

gv = GraphvizOutput()
gv.output_file = 'basic2.png'

config = Config()
config.trace_filter = GlobbingFilter(
    exclude=['pycallgraph.*', '*__init__*'], include=['__main__'])

class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        pass 
    
    def eat(self):
        pass

class Basket:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
    
    def add(self, other):
        self.content.append(other)
    
with PyCallGraph(output=gv, config=config):
    a = Apple()
    b = Basket()
    b.add(a)
    b.content[0].eat()
    
Image.open(gv.output_file)
```

The output image contains the `__init__` methods. Any ideas on how to remove them? In addition I also can't exclude classes and their children (eg. `Apple`)

Ps. I'm using `callgraph4py` (a mantained fork if `pycallgraph`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple fix - the version if the library I installed had the `GlobbingFilter` functionality commented out.

See line 208 here: https://github.com/e-alizadeh/pycallgraph/blob/master/pycallgraph/tracer.py

[image]

Uncommenting lines 208 & 209 fixed my issue.